# How to set the Default gateway

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig, gateway

I'm trying to configure the network interface on embedded linux using ifconfig:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but I don't know how to add the default gateway as an ifconfig parameter,

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please specify which embedded Linux you are using.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`ifconfig` is not the correct command to do that.

You can use `route` like in `route add default gw 192.168.0.254` for example.

And if `route` is not present, but `ip` is, you can use it like this: `ip route add default via 192.168.0.254 dev eth0`, assuming that 192.168.0.254 is the ip of your gateway

Comment: `ip` should be the first choice.`ip r add default via [gw]`.

Answer (score 20):

`ifconfig` is deprecated on Linux and furthermore, it's the wrong tool for the job. To set the default gateway on Linux use the `ip` command as follows:

```
ip route add default via <host> dev <dev>

# e.g.
ip route add default via 192.168.0.101 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 5):

For **remove gateway** in Linux Command : `route delete default gw 192.168.1.1 eth1`

For **add gateway** in Linux Command : `route add default gw 192.168.1.250 eth1`

Answer (score 4):

Using route

```
route add default gw {IP-ADDRESS} {INTERFACE-NAME}
```

example: `route add default gw 192.168.1.2 eth0`

OR use hostname such as dsl-router:

```
route add default gw dsl-router eth0
```

Or use the ip command (newer syntax) to route all traffic via 192.168.1.254 gateway connected via eth0 network interface for example:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

or

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.254
```