# Can't change the default gateway with static IP

Tags: debian, networking, routing, internet, gateway

I have this server for a while, and was present on other questions.

A while ago, I've changed the network and the gateway IP was changed too.
Since then, there is no internet on this machine.

I need access to the internet to update the machine and (sometimes) to install packages I need for development.

What I've tried:

- `route add default gw 192.168.1.1` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259046/133591)
- `ip route replace default via 192.168.1.1` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199070/133591)
- `ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259048/133591)
- Editing the file `/etc/network/interfaces`, to look like below:

  ```
  # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
  # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

  source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

  # The loopback network interface
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  # The primary network interface
  auto eth0
  allow-hotplug eth0
  #iface eth0 inet dhcp
  iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.205
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.1.1
      broadcast 192.168.1.1
  ```

And this is the result of all my attempts:

```
root@webtest:~# route add default gw 192.168.1.1
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
root@webtest:~# ip route replace default via 192.168.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
root@webtest:~# ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
root@webtest:~#
```

The most bizarre thing is the `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable` error, when I'm **clearly** connected using SSH, which used the network.

What else should I try? I don't even know what else to do.

My system is running Debian 8.2 x64, with a single interface network.

---

**Note:**

I have read [How can I change the default gateway?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87543/how-can-i-change-the-default-gateway) and [How to set the Default gateway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259045/how-to-set-the-default-gateway) (which is where I got all those tries from).

The accepted answer on [How can I change the default gateway?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87543/how-can-i-change-the-default-gateway) is a FreeBDS-exclusive answer.

---

Running `ip addr` and `ip route` gives the following:

```
root@webtest:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1a:92:47:00:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.205/24 brd 192.168.1.1 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21a:92ff:fe47:b5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@webtest:~# ip route
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.205
root@webtest:~#
```

---

### Edit 1:

After the change that [@Johan Myréen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/187960/johan-myr%C3%A9en) suggested, the result is still the same.

Below is the updated `ip addr` with 2 pings:

```
root@webtest:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1a:92:47:00:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.205/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21a:92ff:fe47:b5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@webtest:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.205
root@webtest:~# ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
root@webtest:~# ping facebook.com
ping: unknown host facebook.com
root@webtest:~#
```

Comment: What do `ip addr` and `ip route` say?

Comment: @JohanMyréen I've added that information to the question.

Comment: Please refrain from posting images, text is better. Best regards.

Comment: @maulinglawns Should I remove the images?

Comment: Yes, please, they only make it harder to read your question.

Comment: @maulinglawns Alright, the images are gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your broadcast address should be `192.168.1.255`, not `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: Does that require a shutdown? Or restarting the network is enough?

Comment: @Johan Myréen Might be a stupid question, but do we **need** a `broadcast` entry? I only have `address`, `netmask` and `gateway` in my `/etc/network/interfaces` and it works fine!

Comment: Sadly, it didn't fix it. There's no internet on it. Maybe I screwed something? I've updated the question anyway. For a good measure, I've edited the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and rebooted the machine.

Comment: I would say you have made progress. The route is in place, but now you have a DNS problem. Is `/etc/resolv.conf` ok?

Comment: It is showing me this: http://pastebin.com/bkfS9MT9 (vodafonemobile.cpe is the address of the configuration page used by the router)

Comment: Could you try `ping 8.8.8.8` or `traceroute 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @JohanMyréen Weirdly, that works. I can ping it with a ping of ~72ms.

Comment: This confirms that your internet connection is probably perfectly fine, but your DNS is not set up correctly. Are you sure 192.168.1.254 is the correct address of your name server?

Comment: @JohanMyréen It isn't. That's the old gateway. The new one is 192.168.1.1.

Comment: Your old router apparently also functioned as a name resolver. You will have to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add the IP address of your new name server, which is not necessarily to address of your new router.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I'm so sorry for taking so long to answer. I didn't get the notification of the comment. Yes, editing the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and changing every instance of `192.168.1.254` to `192.168.1.1` solved it. I've marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Since your "Edit 1" comments, you would notice that `route -n` now shows a default gateway. Having ping replying with `unknown host` may just be related to your DNS configuration. Try ping-ing IPs instead.

Note: in your `/etc/network/interfaces`, the `allow-hotplug eth0` may not be necessary.

Comment: It actually was a mix of your answer and Johan Myréen's answer. Which includes a bit of yours. I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

From configuration you have done on ip and netmask, Assuming your subnet is /24. Then you broadcast will be 192.168.1.255

Comment: That is exactly what @Johan Myréen said five minutes ago...